# updated from angular 5 to angular 6 and can't build a dist folder anymore

Tags: angular, build, production-environment, angular6, rxjs6

this is my setup:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@angular/cli                 6.0.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         5.5.11
typescript                   2.4.2
```

And I've tried:

- ng build
- ng build --prod
- ng build --environment=prod
- ng build --target=production --environment=prod
- ng build --prod --env=prod
- npm run build etc. etc.

I am now at a complete loss as to why the dist is not getting built, I'd really appreciate it if anybody could help

Comment: If using angular cli 6, you probably need angular 6 as well. Follow the steps here https://update.angular.io/ to migrate your angular 5 project. And it'd be good if you included any error you get from the console..

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 6, you need RxJS 6.

From the Docs:

> ## 6.0.0 (2018-05-03)
>
> ### Dependency updates
>
> @angular/core now depends on
>
> - TypeScript 2.7
> - RxJS 6.0.0
> - tslib 1.9.0
>
> @angular/platform-server now depends on
>
> - Domino 2.0
>
> — https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#dependency-updates

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers but the solution to my question is a little embarrassing... I was building the dist folder via jenkins and in my script I copy a package.json file back in because each package.json file that I copy, points to a different server before the dist build - hence all the updates were getting overwritten by the old package.json file (i had forgotten to update this!!)... I told you it was a little embarrassing - but thank you for your time though, appreciate it